# Extending or adding functions to modules of Node

Tags: node.js

I want to add few methods to async package for my project requirements.. I don't want to change js file of aync. How to extend a module of Node to add more functions?

When I do require('myasync') I want all the functions of 'async' module and also the functions that I added.

Comment: If you're requiring the async module, how do you think it will grab the other functions without altering the async module? No. You'll have to edit the async module or require your own

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The steps in order to complete this would be:

- Get the module's pre-defined functionality as your own variable
- Modify, delete, and/or append more functionality to the variable (via Javascript's functional paradigm)
- Re-export the variable as your own, which allows you to `require` it (either as an NPM module or as a file module).

First, we require async.

```
var newModule = require('async');
```

Now that we've retrieved the module `async`, we can append our own function.

```
newModule.betterParallel = function(myParameters) { ... };
```

Not only can we add our own function, but we can even delete from the module - since it is now our own.

```
delete newModule['series'];
```

With that completed, we need to then re-export our new module.

```
module.exports = newModule;
```

If you want to publish this to NPM as your own module, you can use `npm publish`. If you don't want to, you can simply `require` this file - and now it contains your modified changes.

Comment: Is it at all possible to import the original module with the extensions instead of needing to import your new, extended version?

Comment: @merlinpatt in this case `require('async')` should actually carry your changes within the same process, although this relies on the module system behavior — which is why I recommend re-exporting your own.

Answer (score 9):

```
// module that you like to extend
var async = require('async')

// add a new function, myOwnFunction, to the module
async.myOwnFunction = function () {
  // do something
}

// re-export the module, for the changes to take effect
module.exports = async
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation as to how this answers the question? Dropping code only without explanation is usually not very valuable.

Answer (score 1):

If the module exports an `Object`, my personal taste is:

```js
import moduleToExtend from "moduleToExtend";

const myModule = {
    newFunction1: function () {
        // some new stuff
    },
    newFunction2: function () {
        // some new stuff
    },
};

module.exports = Object.assign(moduleToExtend, myModule);
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The Object.assign() method copies all enumerable own properties from
>   one or more source objects to a target object. It returns the target
>   object.